# What is function that gets query params in Next.js 13 Server app directory

Tags: typescript, next.js

I want to get query token in `localhost/get/point?token=hello`.

```js
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import base64url from 'base64url'

type Params = {
  token: string
}

export async function GET(req: Request, context: { params: Params }) {
  
  const token = req.query.token


  const tokenData = JSON.parse(base64url.decode(token.split('.')[1]))
  const verifyResult = Jwt.verify(token)
  if (verifyResult == JwtStatusCode.TokenExpired) {
    return NextResponse.json({ error: 'Token expired', message: 'Token expired'}, { status: 401 })
  } else if (verifyResult === JwtStatusCode.TokenInvalid) {
    return NextResponse.json({ error: 'Token invalid', message: 'Token invalid' }, { status: 401 })
  }
  const data = await client.user.findMany({
    where: { name: tokenData.name }
  })
  if (data.length != 0) {
    NextResponse.json({
      point: data[0].point,
      message: 'Success'
    }, { status: 200 })
  }
}
```

In pages directory, I used to use req.query but what is it in Next13 app directory?

I tried url split but I think it isn't efficient.

Answer (score 1):

It can be solved by using URL object and searchParams.
`searchParms.get` function can get query params in Next.js 13

```js
const { searchParams } = new URL(req.url)
const token = searchParams.get('token') as string
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**